# Django bootstrap css 404 Not found

Tags: django, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to load in bootstrap into my html page but I get a 404 status code in the network tab in the developers tools saying that it could not find the file
the request url is
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css

this is my html page where I am trying to use to the file

```
<!-- templates/base.html -->
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Dog Groomers</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.css' %}"/>
</head>
</html>
```

Here is my file structure

[image]

in my settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

#edit wasn't included before in question
DEBUG = TRUE
```

Do I need to have a static folder in every folder instead of just having it in the root?

Comment: what is value of DEBUG ? True or False?

Comment: Debug is set to True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly update your settings.py

You are using this:
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

Try this one, it should work!

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)